# "Es sieht so aus, als (ob)" with conditional

Tags: meaning, conjunction

Here is a sentence in English

> It looks like that big egg will take more time.

I had a go at translating it myself and this is what I got

> Es sieht so aus, als ob das große Ei mehr Zeit dauern würde

So I basically used the "als ob" Nebensatz, and since the action in the Nebensatz happens after the Hauptsatz, I opted for a conditional. Is this correct?  It is just that DeepL begs to differ

> Es sieht so aus, als würde das große Ei mehr Zeit in Anspruch nehmen

Comment: "dauern" is definitely the wrong verb, DeepL is right to say "in Anspruch nehmen"; another verb you can use is "brauchen"

Answer (score 4):

These are *vergleichende Relativsätze*. When their purpose is to give a *ungenauee Einschätzung* (a vague impression (?) )...

... you can use any of the following:

> Es sieht so aus, **als** *würde* das große Ei mehr Zeit brauchen.
> Es sieht so aus, **als ob** das große Ei mehr Zeit brauchen *würde*.
> Es sieht so aus, **als wenn** das große Ei mehr Zeit brauchen *würde*.
> Es sieht so aus, **wie wenn** das große Ei mehr Zeit brauchen *würde*.

Dudengrammar 2009 Nr.1671 and 1688

Comment: oder auch mit Konjunktiv I: "...als nehme das große Ei mehr Zeit in Anspruch" (und entsprechend) oder auch nähme(?)

Comment: Yes, but Konjunktiv II is much more common. Semantically, no Konjunktiv is needed anyway.

Comment: @323242323242: I disagree, *Konjunktiv* (subjunctive mood) stating just an unproven possiblity is sufficient without resorting to *als ob*. *More common* may be true for conversation, but can hardly be considered as a reason not to use it.

Comment: As this sentence is talking about an egg 'in Anspruch nehmen' sounds awkwardly overformal. I would just use 'brauchen' here. Of course there are contexts where 'in Anspruch nehmen' is good and correct but the cook time of an egg isn't.